# Will deprecated classes raise any security issues?

Tags: apex, security, security-review

I submitted my managed package for a security review few days ago. After submitting, I found out that I don't have to use an Apex class in the package. So, I tried to delete that class but couldn't because it was part of a managed package. So, I annotated that class with `@deprecated`.
2 days ago, I got the result and `CRUD/FLS Enforcement` issue is raised on this class. Now, the problem is, **I cannot edit this class** as it throws this error: `A class with name was deprecated for this package or this name is already in use`, also **I cannot delete the class**. I went to [Salesforce Partner Community](https://partners.salesforce.com/) and raised a ticket and got the permission to delete the managed classes. But, still I cannot delete the class(I don't know why). So, my question is, **if I submit the package for security review again, will it raise the same issue again or ignore the issue as the class is now deprecated?**

Comment: You can just wipe out the deprecated class, I mean, just leave only class declaration like ```public class DeprecatedClass {}```, then it will pass security review easily and you won't need to worry about it.

Comment: @MariiaIllarionova thats what I tried to do. But, as i have mentioned in my question, I cannot edit the class.